# Interact with another program from C++ (POSIX??)

Tags: c++, unix, posix

I made my first GUI for Unix with QT. At the end of my GUI I start another program, which is based on python. There the user would need to press one button to complete the process.
Now I want to automate that last click. I already read a little about POSIX but I'm not quite sure if it can help me. I was thinking that, if I wont be able to access the programm directly, maybe I could at least set to mouse to a certain position and simulate a click? I know this solution is very dirty, but it might work because I will be using the GUI on one certain touch screen only

Comment: Maybe use `system()` to call `xdotool` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html Or code it yourself... http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/simulating-a-mouse-click-594576/

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkSetchell xdotool was exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately the program Iam starting blocks the terminal. I can't enter any commands as long as the programm runs. My work around right now looks like this: python program.py & // sleep 10 // xdotool search program